# How to make radioButton text choices bold in R Shiny?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I need to make the text choices bold in my radioButton Shiny widget.  I am trying to use the "choiceNames" and "choiceValues" options in the widget.  However, I am getting an error that reads: "Error in list(tags$span(style = "{#p.thick font-weight: bold;}", "Valid"),  : argument 6 is empty".

```
    column(width = 2,
           wellPanel(style = "background-color: #d2d369; font-weight: bold;",
                     p(strong(h3("Quality Control Tests"))),
                     tags$hr(style="border-color: black;"),
                     div(style="column-count: 2;",
                         radioButtons('qcRoutineRadioButtons', label = NULL, 
                                      choiceNames = list(
                                        tags$span(style = "font-weight: bold;", "Valid"), 
                                        tags$span(style = "font-weight: bold;", "Spike"), 
                                        tags$span(style = "font-weight: bold;", "Streak"), 
                                        tags$span(style = "font-weight: bold;", "EPA"), 
                                        tags$span(style = "font-weight: bold;", "MADIS"), 
                                      ),
                                      choiceValues = list('valid', 'spike', 'streak','epa','madis'), selected = 'valid')
                     )
           )
    ),
```

What does that error mean?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have a superfluous comma after `tags$span(style = "font-weight: bold;", "MADIS")`, so the list expects one more argument. If you remove it, it works

Comment: You can also wrap with tags$b("Valid"), instead of tags$span(...)